# Calculating right time in clock angle problem

Tags: recreational-mathematics

A clock is set right at 5 a.m. The clock loses 16 minutes in 24 hours.What will be the true time when the clock indicates 10 p.m. on 4th day?

I am completely messed up in this question. Can anyone please explain it with each step.

Comment: What will be the indicated time 24h at 5am the next day?

Answer (score 3):

The clock loses 16 minutes every 24 hours, which means that it loses
$$ \frac{16\text{ minutes}}{24 \text{ hour}} = \frac{2}{3} \frac{\text{min}}{\text{hr}}$$
minutes every hour.  In order to figure out what time it *really* is when the clock says 10 PM on the 4th day, we need to figure out how much time has really past since 5 AM on the first day, and compare that to how much time the clock *indicates* has passed.  Let us call this actual number of hours $T$ (or the **T**ime that has passed), and let $S$ be the number of hours that the clock **S**hows have passed.  Note that
$$ 60 \frac{\text{min}}{\text{hr}}\cdot S\text{ hr} = 60\frac{\text{min}}{\text{hr}}\cdot T \text{ hr} - \frac{2}{3}\frac{\text{min}}{\text{hr}}\cdot T \text{ hr}. $$
That is, the time shown is the actual time, minus $\frac{2}{3}$ of a minute for every hour that has actually passed.  Now, we actually know what $S$ is:  the clock indicates that 3 days and 17 hours have passed, which means that (dropping the units, because I am tired of editing them in)
$$ S = 3\cdot 24 + 17 = 89. $$
Solving for $T$, we get
$$ 60 S = \left( 60 - \frac{2}{3} \right)T = \frac{180-2}{3} T = \frac{178}{3} T
\implies T = \frac{60\cdot 2}{178}S = \frac{180}{178}S = \frac{90}{89}(80) = 90.
$$
Thus the actual amount of time that has elapsed is 90 hours.  That is, 3 days (72 hours) and 18 hours have elapsed.  Thus the actual time is 18 hours past 5 AM, or 11 PM on the 4th day.

Comment: But 10pm is not true time, but the time the clock shows.

Comment: @Ennar Oops!  I read that backwards!  Give me minute

Comment: Okay, this might sound lame, but how can you say this "16/24" as this is minute to hour ratio? why is hour not converted to minutes?

Comment: Sure. Funnily, interpreted the right way, true time is "rigged" to be nice solution :)

Comment: @nban, just add units: it should read $16\,\text{min}/24\,\text{h} = 2/3\, \text{min/h}$.

Answer (score 1):

When we say a clock "loses" 16 minutes each day. What does that precisely mean? At the end of the day, the clock reads $11:44$. Thus, when $1$ hour has elapsed, the clock has "lost" $\frac23$ of a minute, or $40$ seconds. Let's use the word "cl-minutes" to denote what this clock calls a minute. Our conversion factor is this:

$$59\frac13\text{ cl-minutes} = 60\text{ minutes}$$

Now, from $5$am on day $1$ to $10$pm on day $4$ is a duration of $19+24+24+22$ hours, or $89$ cl-hours total. That's $5340$ cl-minutes.

$$\begin{align} 5340\text{ cl-min}\times\frac{60\text{ min}}{59\frac13\text{ cl-min}} &= \left(5340\times60\div\frac{178}{3}\right)\text{ min}\\
&= 5400\text{ min}\\
&= 90\text{ hours}
\end{align}$$

It is actually $11:00$pm

Comment: Something went wrong, the clock is being late, so true time should be >10pm, right?

Comment: Yes, I had it backwards. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Let us interpret what "losing $16$ minutes in $24$ hours" means: when $24$ true hours pass, the clock will show that $23$ hours and $44$ minutes have passed (thus, it "lost" $16$ minutes). I will denote with $h$ true hour, and with $fh$ fake hour that the clock shows, so we can write the sentence as $$24\, h = (24-\frac{16}{60})\, fh$$

*(division by $60$ is because $1$ hour = $60$ minutes)*

Dividing by $24$ we get

$$1\, h = (1 - \frac{16}{24\cdot 60})\, fh = (1-\frac{2}{3\cdot 60})\,fh =(1- \frac 1{90})\,fh = \frac{89}{90}\, fh,$$

and if we multiply by $90$, we get that $90\,h = 89\,fh$.

So, let us say that we started at $5\,\mathrm{am}$ Monday and ask ourselves how much (fake) time had passed when the clock shows $10\,\mathrm{pm}$ Thursday. It is $3$ (fake) days to get to $5\,\mathrm{am}$ Thursday plus $17$ (fake) hours to get to $10\,\mathrm{pm}$ Thursday, and the total is $(3\cdot 24 + 17)\, fh = 89 fh$, but $89\, fh = 90\,h$, so to get true time, we need to add $90\,h$ to $5\,\mathrm{am}$ Monday. Luckily, we can use what we know, that if we add $89$ hours, we will get to $10\,\mathrm{pm}$ Thursday, and adding another hour gives us $11\,\mathrm{pm}$ Thursday of true time.